# Moving a site to a new group

Tags: localization, multi-site

Got a question regarding site groups and more specifically about the possible data loss.

Scenario is as follows: I have a site A and site B in the same group. Client now wants both sites available in a second language so I'd like to switch this setup to two groups: group 1 will have site A in dutch & english, group 2 will have site B in dutch & english.

What are the risks of moving a site to a different group? (edited)

[image: as seen in the control panel]

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about data loss, I would duplicate the site locally as a test install and try on there. If that works fine, I would backup files and DB again before modifying groups on my dev install.

TBH I don't recall having data losses by switching goups, but that's not something I typically do every day.